# How to archive Exchange mailboxes remotely?

Tags: exchange, outlook

We have an environment that is based on an Active Directory domain (running Windows Server 2003 SP2), an internal email system using Exchange Server 2003 (internal mailbox, nothing online), and the clients run a mixture of MS Outlook 2007&2010, with the majority running 2007.

Recently we noticed that Exchange server is taking so much space for mailboxes. We are examining some solutions to reduce space, and it seems that we could make use of the archiving feature to archive older messages. I can set the auto-archive option manually for every individual user, but is there any other easier way to automate that task? Is there any feature in exchange server or active directory domain that enables setting that as a kind of policy or something similar, or a script to be scheduled to run by all users?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of AutoArchive settings available in Group Policy. download the Office 2007 and Office 2010 Group Policy templates and add them to a GPO for your Outlook client computers and configure according to your needs.